# Processing of images mathematically

Tags: windows-7, batch, automation, cmd.exe

I have numerous images from a directory that needs to be subtracted to another image(another directory) and I don't know how to do it automatically in batch process. Any idea?

The following are the goals for the batch file:

- Create an output directory
- Create a proc_path directory for the processed files only
- Subtract image from the directory to another image from another
  directory

Did my best to create some part of this script. Sorry if it's too messy, I know I'm not doing the right thing. I hope you understand.

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "in_path=E:\Proc\Mer\"
set "out_path=E:\Proc\Abcde"
set "two_path=E:\Proc\Me\"
set "proc_path=E:\Proc\Proc_Mer_Fi"

::Don't modify the following variables
set "yearDay="
set "fileList="

md %out_path%
md %proc_path%

::Process all *.tif files in input path
cd /d "%in_path%"
for %%a in (*.tif) do (
   set "fileName=%%a" 
   if %1 == 001-031 goto :condition1 ::reg/leap
   if %2 == 032-059 goto :condition2 ::reg
   if %3 == 032-060 goto :condition2 ::leap
   if %4 == 060-090 goto :condition3 ::reg
   if %5 == 061-091 goto :condition3 ::leap
   if %6 == 091-120 goto :condition4 ::reg
   if %7 == 092-121 goto :condition4 ::leap
   if %8 == 121-151 goto :condition5 ::reg
   if %9 == 122-152 goto :condition5 ::leap
   if %10 == 152-181 goto :condition6 ::reg
   if %11 == 153-182 goto :condition6 ::leap
   if %12 == 182-212 goto :condition7 ::reg
   if %13 == 183-213 goto :condition7 ::leap
   if %14 == 213-243 goto :condition8 ::reg
   if %15 == 214-244 goto :condition8 ::leap
   if %16 == 244-273 goto :condition9 ::reg
   if %17 == 245-274 goto :condition9 ::leap
   if %18 == 274-304 goto :condition10 ::reg
   if %19 == 275-305 goto :condition10 ::leap
   if %20 == 305-334 goto :condition11 ::reg
   if %21 == 306-335 goto :condition11 ::leap
   if %22 == 335-365 goto :condition12 ::reg
   if %23 == 336-366 goto :condition12 ::leap

   :condition1
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_jan.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition2
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_feb.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition3
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_mar.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition4
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_apr.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition5
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_may.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition6
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_june.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition7
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition8
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_aug.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition9
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_sep.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition10
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_oct.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition11
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_nov.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :condition12
   gdal_calculate --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" --two=%two_path%\two_abc_dec.tif --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! --extent=INTERSECT
   goto end
   :: Move processed files to a different directory
   for %%a in (!fileList!) do move %%a "%proc_path%" >nul
```

Comment: So many problems here, don't know where to start. Why are you checking command line parameters %1 to %23? Are you passing 23 parameters to the batch file? FYI, only %1 to %9 are allowed; after that, you must use the `shift` command. See `shift /?` for further info.

Comment: Inside your `for` loop, use `call :conditionX` instead of `goto`, otherwise you'll jump out of the loop and never return to it. Make sure to close your loop before declaring the condition handlers. Inside the condition handlers, instead of `goto end`, use `goto :eof`.

Comment: Why the restriction _::Don't modify the following variables_ `set "yearDay="` and `set "fileList="`? You _have to_ modify them, as next used in `dal_calculate` calls. And in that calls you use e.g. `%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif` which results to `E:\Proc\Mer\\A...` (doubled backslash). And what about the leap years?

Comment: @JosefZ see edit for the filename. That's the reason why the `set "yearDay=` and `set "fileList="` is set to blank. Because there are many files and the yearDay changes. I hope I'm getting your point?

Comment: @wardies, because there are many conditions I have to make that's why  I thought of creating up to %23. How will I modify this script? I really don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The below batch script browses all files of a `????????*.tif` template in the `%in_path%` folder with no recursion. By entry, the 2nd-8th characters of file name indicate Julian date `YearDay` of the `yyyyddd` pattern. Browsing the files determined by further conditions specified in the question and additional comments.

- at first, the `%in_path%` folder browsed to create a list of `YearDay`s: see initial `for %%Q` loop; then
- each `YearDay` processed in an outer `for %%p` loop where is, as a side effect, computed *common* date of the `yyyy-mmm-dd` format;
- files of the same `YearDay` processed apart in an inner 'for %%G' loop and there is a list of files (the same `YearDay`) filled out;
- last mentioned list is completed as soon as inner loop will be over.

The code

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "in_path=E:\Proc\Mer"
set "out_path=E:\Proc\Abcde"
set "two_path=E:\Proc\Me"
set "proc_path=E:\Proc\Proc_Mer_Fi"
md %in_path%   2> NUL
md %out_path%  2> NUL
md %two_path%  2> NUL
md %proc_path% 2> NUL

pushd "%in_path%\"

set "yearDay="
set "fileName="

::Get list of all YearDays in input path
set "yearDayList=x"
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%Q in ('dir /B ????????*.tif') do (
  set "fileName=%%Q"
  set "yearDay=!fileName:~1,7!"
  Call :ItemToList !yearDayList! !yearDay!
)
@set yearDayList=%yearDayList:x= %
@echo yearDayList=%yearDayList%

::Process all *.tif files in input path day by day
for %%p in ( %yearDayList%) Do ( 
  set "yearDay=%%p"
  @echo .
  set /A "julYr=!yearDay:~0,4!"
  set "julDayS=!yearDay:~4,3!"
  set "month="
  set "monthDay="
  rem avoid octal conversions
  if "!julDayS:~0,2!"=="00" (
    set /A "julDn=!julDayS:~2,1!"
  ) else (
    if "!julDayS:~0,1!"=="0" (
      set /A "julDn=!julDayS:~1,2!"
    ) else (
      set /A "julDn=!julDayS!"
    )
  )
  call :months !julYr! !julDn!
  set "mDay2=0!monthDay!"
  set "mDay2=!mDay2:~-2!"
  @echo p^:  yearDay !yearDay!   yyyy-mmm-dd !julYr!-!month!-!mDay2!
  @rem p^:  yearDay !yearDay!   yyyy-mmm-d !julYr!-!month!-!monthDay!

  rem Process all *.tif files of the same YearDay in input path
  set "fileList="
  for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%G in ('dir /B "?%%p*.tif"') do (
    set "fileName=%%G"
    set "fileList=!fileList!!fileName! "
    @echo G^: !fileName!
  )
  REM   @echo fileList=!fileList!
  REM   @echo Move processed files ^(one day^) to a different directory
  REM   for %%a in (!fileList!) do (
  REM     @echo move %%a "%proc_path%\"
  REM   )
)
popd
goto :allcommon

:allcommon
@ENDLOCAL
@goto :eof

:ItemToList
rem yearDayList yearDay
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
  set "myYDList=%1"
  set "myYearDay=%2"
  set "myYList="
  call :myset "myYList=%%myYDList:%myYearDay%=%%"
  if "%myYList%"=="%myYDList%" set "myYDList=%myYDList%x%myYearDay%"
ENDLOCAL & set "yearDayList=%myYDList%"
exit /B

:months
rem %1=julYr
rem %2=julDn
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "mymonth=XXX"
set /a "dayom=%2"
set "allmonths=Xjanfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec"
set /a "ii=1"
rem leap year test makes use of integer only arithmetic
set /A "yearModi=(%1/4)*4"
If "%1"=="%yearModi%" (
  rem leap year
  set "daycounts=32 61 92 122 153 183 214 245 275 306 336 367"
) Else (
  rem non-leap year
  set "daycounts=32 60 91 121 152 182 213 244 274 305 335 366"
)
For %%G in (%daycounts%) do (
  if %2 lss %%G (
    call :myset "mymonth=%%allmonths:~!ii!,3%%"
    rem set /a "dayom+=1"
    goto :commmonths
  )
  set /a ii=!ii!+3
  set /a "dayom=%2-%%G+1"
)
:commmonths
ENDLOCAL & (set "month=%mymonth%"
set "monthDay=%dayom%")
exit /B

:myset
rem procedure to set indirect variable replace/substring
rem i.e. dynamic %StrToFind% instead of literal StrToFind
rem common: set "varNew=%varOld:StrToFind=NewStr%"
rem call :myset "varNew=%%varOld:%varToFind%=NewStr%%"
rem call :myset "varNew=%%varOld:!varToFind!=NewStr%%"
rem applicable to %NewStr% as well
rem i.e. dynamic %CharsToSkip% instead of literal CharsToSkip
rem common: set "varNew=%varOld:~CharsToSkip,chars_to_keep%"
rem call :myset "varNew=%%varOld:~%CharsToSkip%,chars_to_keep%%"
rem call :myset "varNew=%%varOld:~!CharsToSkip!,chars_to_keep%%"
rem applicable to %chars_to_keep% as well
set %1
exit /B
```

There are some *(un)common* techniques and rules of code readability used in the script:

- some procedures end with `ENDLOCAL & set "globalVar=%localVar%"`; by putting `ENDLOCAL & SET` commands on a single line we are able to `SET` a variable just before the localisation is ended by the `ENDLOCAL` command;
- procedure `:ItemToList` concatenates second parameter passed to end of first parameter if and only if is not present there; uncommon `x` delimiter is replaced by common `space` in the complete list only;
- procedure `:months` returns short month name and day number in the month with respect of leap/non-leap year; input parameters are year and *julian* day number;
- procedure `:myset` involved to set indirect variable replace/substring; self-explained by `rem`s in the code;
- note a code snippet headed `avoid octal conversions` within the `for %%p` loop; a bit complicated, as numeric values would have considered octal by command interpreter when prefixed by zero...
- note all consistently coupled `SETLOCAL` with `ENDLOCAL` and `pushd` with `popd`
- if `()` parentheses span a code block of multiple lines, then every `)` *ending parenthesis* is indented on a new line to the same column as corresponding keyword `for` or `if` except `else` which is counted as a part of `if`;
- all paths are, as a matter of general principle, defined with *no trailing backslash*; add the `\` backslash when a path is *used* if necessary

Comment: where should I put the gdal_calculate command?

Comment: Sorry, I know _nothing_ about image processing or even about the `gdal_calculate` command... The only thing I wanted was to help you with getting _values_ of variables I have recognized in _your_ `gdal_calculate` call, regardless of their (dis)proper use.

Comment: Here is the output of the second code you gave `yearDayList=  2009274 2009275 2009276
.
p:  yearDay 2009274   yyyy-mmm-dd 2009-oct-01
G: A2009274.Q_WER.Tera.tif
.
p:  yearDay 2009275   yyyy-mmm-dd 2009-oct-02
G: A2009275.Q_WER.Tera.tif
.
p:  yearDay 2009276   yyyy-mmm-dd 2009-oct-03
G: A2009276.Q_WER.Tera.tif`

Comment: In which part of the code you gave should I put the gdal_calculate command?In your first code you were able to put the gdal_calculate command.

Comment: When I tried to insert the gdal_calculate after `rem Process all *.tif files of the same YearDay in input path
  set "fileList="` the code run and calculate only one image from the input directory. And there's still lot of errors like `Missing operator.
Missing operator.
Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script.` and `RuntimeError: `--two=%two_path%\two_abc_!month!.tif ' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.` But I know I'm getting close.

Comment: The in_path and the two_path shouldn't be created because they are already created and they already have the files needed for the calculation. The proc_path and the out_path should be created.

Comment: 1. `md %in_path% 2> NUL` has no effect if the `%in_path%` exists already but ensures its existence; 2. Try to insert the gdal_calculate after `@echo G^: !fileName!` rather; 3. For debugging purposes, prefix your command with `echo ` to see whether it's right (in syntax at least)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code: all `move`s are echoed, All original `gdal_calculate` calls are substituted by one with `!month!` instead of `jan`, `feb` etc. Resulting `gdal_calculate` is echoed to five lines, each line = one `--parameter`. Some seem to be quite bit weird, in particular those containing (growing) `!fileList!`

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "in_path=E:\Proc\Mer\"
set "out_path=E:\Proc\Abcde"
set "two_path=E:\Proc\Me\"
set "proc_path=E:\Proc\Proc_Mer_Fi\"

set "yearDay="
set "fileList="
set "fileName="

md %in_path%   2> NUL
md %out_path%  2> NUL
md %two_path%  2> NUL
md %proc_path% 2> NUL

::Process all *.tif files in input path
pushd "%in_path%"
for %%G in (*.tif) do (
  set "fileName=%%G"
  set "yearDay=!fileName:~1,7!"
  set /A "julYr=!fileName:~1,4!"
  set "julDayS=!fileName:~5,3!"
  set "month="
  rem avoid octal conversions
  if "!julDayS:~0,2!"=="00" (
    set /A "julDn=!julDayS:~2,1!"
  ) else (
    if "!julDayS:~0,1!"=="0" (
      set /A "julDn=!julDayS:~1,2!"
    ) else (
      set /A "julDn=!julDayS!"
    )
  )
  call :months !julYr! !julDn!
  set "fileList=!fileList!!fileName! "
  @echo .
  @echo !fileName! yearDay=!yearDay! julYr=!julYr! julDn=!julDn! month=!month!
  rem next lines display original gdal_calculate call
  rem each line = one --parameter
  rem some seem to be quite bit weird
  rem in particular those containing !fileList!
  @rem echo gdal_calculate 
  @echo --outfile=%out_path%\Abcde!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! 
  @echo --calc="((one-two)/(one+two))" 
  @echo --two=%two_path%\two_abc_!month!.tif 
  @echo --one=%in_path%\A!yearDay!.Q_WER.Tera.tif !fileList! 
  @echo --extent=INTERSECT
)
rem Move processed files to a different directory
for %%a in (%fileList%) do @echo move %%a "%proc_path%"
goto :allcommon

:allcommon
popd
@ENDLOCAL
@goto :eof

:months
rem %1=julYr
rem %2=julDn
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "mymonth=XXX"
set "allmonths=Xjanfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec"
set /a "ii=1"
rem leap year test makes use of integer only arithmetic
set /A "yearReal=%1"
set /A "yearModi=(%yearReal%/4)*4"
If "%yearReal%"=="%yearModi%" (
  rem leap year
  set "daycounts=32 61 92 122 153 183 214 245 275 306 336 366"
) Else (
  rem non-leap year
  set "daycounts=32 60 91 121 152 182 213 244 274 305 335 365"
)
rem echo %daycounts% "%yearReal%" "%yearModi%"
For %%G in (%daycounts%) do (
  if %2 lss %%G (
    call :myset "set mymonth=%%allmonths:~!ii!,3%%"
    goto :commonmonths
  )
  set /a ii=!ii!+3
)
:commonmonths
ENDLOCAL & set month=%mymonth%
exit /B

:myset
%~1
exit /B
```

Comment: thank you for the effort in creating the script. The fileList variable keep the list of all filenames of the same YearDay. And there is no way to know in advance how many files of the same YearDay are, so this variable is initialized to an empty string at beginning.

Comment: Can you explain the codes you used?